# Submitting 2 Forms with 1 Button or 1 Input

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dropzone

currently i have 2 Buttons (well 1 Button and 1 Input with a Bootstrap button class) I use to upload a picture, and add a text to that picutre.

Ofcourse thats not a good way to handle it, and i would like to merge these 2 buttons into 1.

First uploading the picture (triggering the dropzone script) and then adding the Text from a form to a SQL Database.

I have to idea if its even possible to combine that into one.

I have my code shown below.

```
<!-- PICTURE UPLOAD USING DROPZONE -->
<form action="upload/doupload.php" class="dropzone" id="datenhochlad" ></form>


<!-- FORM TABLE TO INPUT TEXT WHICH SHALL BE SENT TO SQL  -->
        <form method="post" id="texteingabetabelle">
            <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Text zum Bild:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="eingabe" type="text" name="bildtext" width="100px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bild ID:  <?php echo $bildid+1 ?></td>
                    </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>

<!-- BUTTON TO EXECUTE DROPZONE -> UPLOADING THE PICTURE -->
        <center><button type="submit" id="hochladdaten" class="btn btn-primary">Bild Hochladen</button><center>
<br>

<!-- BUTTON TO EXECUTE THE SQL QUERY  -->
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="hochladdaten" name="hochladdaten" value="Text Senden" />

        </form>




            <!-- SQL STUFF -->
            <?php

    if(isset($_POST['hochladdaten']))
        {
            $bildtext = $_POST['bildtext'];
                sleep(5);

            $omadbconnect->query("insert into bildertexte(text,bildid) values('$bildtext', '$bildid' )");
            sleep(1);
            header('Location: index.php');
        if(!$omadbconnect) 
        { echo mysqli_error();
         }
    else
    {

    }

         }  

    ?>
```

Comment: use javascript with this.

Comment: You can add more buttons to a html form and check in PHP which button actually got clicked in the $_REQUEST array.

Comment: I dont see two buttons in that code. I see a text `input`, and a `button`. Also keep in mind, using `button` tags will not submit any value by default with the key in the `$_REQUEST` unless you also specify a `value="something"` on the tag (which you do not have). ... But Short answer: what hassan said.

Comment: right, there are no 2 buttons @IncredibleHat , i got an <input> classed as a button, and a <button> and would like to merge these two either into 1 <input> or into 1 <button>

Comment: @hassan could you show me a snippet ? im not used to JS atall

Comment: This can spiral... so I would suggest using jquery, since it will simplify the use of javascript greatly for you. However since you are dealing with another js library (the dropzone uploader action), you will need to familiarize yourself with what triggers it is using, and either piggy-back on it (to issue a form submit on success), or write your own interceptor and fully control what is going on. The former choice is simpler.

Comment: @IncredibleHat sounds like a stupid amount of work for such a little thing

Comment: LOL... sometimes yes ;) Thats the JS way!

Comment: i was still not able to figure any way to do this....